# What does Excel VBA keyword Any exactly mean?

Tags: excel, vba

This is more of a curiosity than a practical problem at this point, but I'd like to find documentation on the `Any` keyword in Excel.

I'm doing a bit of using Windows API programming in VBA.

For example, the answer for [A good substitute for references/pointers in VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39143998/a-good-substitute-for-references-pointers-in-vba) includes `Any`.

As one can imagine, searching for "Excel VBA keyword Any" brings up a lot answers with the word "any" and not the keyword `Any`.

I tried `Dim x As Any` and Excel didn't like it so it doesn't seem a normal data type.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, that tells me I can't use `Any`, but doesn't really define what `Any` is. How many bytes, differences between 32-bit Excel and 64-bit for example. Really just looking for a formal definition.

Comment: `Any` is ***not*** a keyword in Excel. The user of `Any` on the page to which you link  is part of declarations *in the Windows API* function, where it does have meaning.